# How can I delete the Boom application output device from my system?

Tags: macos, mac, audio

I uninstalled the [Boom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boom-experience-best-audio/id415312377?mt=12) application, I can’t find any files related to Boom in my system—maybe I am missing something?—but I still have this in my output devices configuration:

[image]

How can I delete the Boom output device in those configurations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this QA was originally posted, the developers now have a full uninstaller app at https://www.globaldelight.com/boom3d/mas-content/uninstall.php which should save any manual intervention being necessary.

---

- Check for `BoomDevice.kext` in `/System/Library/Extensions`. 
  If present, delete it.
- Delete Boom app [if you didn't already].
- Reboot.
- Confirm that BoomDevice has been removed from System Sound Preferences.

EDIT:
Also remove any BoomDevice related files from these places:

/System/Library/Extensions

/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins

~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins (which is the above folder in your Home directory)

Once done, restart your system. The BoomDevice profiles from your audio settings should be gone now.

Found this extremely helpful answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/442016

Answer (score 68):

Open Terminal app and run the following command(s)...

- To remove BoomDevice

```
sudo kextunload -b com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice
```

- To remove Boom2Device

```
sudo kextunload -b com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device
```

This should do the trick and you even don’t need to reboot your Mac.

Comment: this has bugged me for a long time, fix totally works!

Comment: FYI it's now two years later and somehow that driver keeps came back. I re-ran this command also Tom's command from another answer (`rm -rf ~/Music/Boom{,\ 2}`) - fingers-crossed!

Answer (score 30):

Execute the following commands in a (bash) terminal window.

To uninstall Boom (v1) and remove BoomDevice:

```
killall Boom
sudo kextunload -b com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Boom.app /Library/Extensions/BoomDevice.kext
```

To uninstall Boom2 and remove Boom2Device:

```
killall Boom\ 2
sudo kextunload -b com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Boom\ 2.app /Library/Extensions/Boom2Device.kext
killall com.globaldelight.Boom2Daemon
```

You do not need to reboot, the effect is immediate.

Further, to wipe out Boom's profile(s)/config settings (e.g. if you don't plan on reinstalling Boom in future, or want to have a clean slate if you do decide to), you can finally execute:

```
rm -rf ~/Music/Boom{,\ 2}
```

Comment: Jan 2018 - Updated this to include removal of an additional Boom2 service, and removal of profile/configuration data

Comment: This is the best answer, IMO

Answer (score 4):

Tetsujin's answer is not correct actually, the Kernel Extension file is not in /System/Library/Extensions but in /Library/Extensions and it's called Boom2Device.kext – you have to delete this one to get rid of the Boom2Device.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Uninstall Boom Device](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/download/installers/mavericks/uninstall-boom-device.html) script from it's creators. It simply runs these commands:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/BoomDevice.kext
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/BoomDevice.kext
```

Comment: Use https://www.globaldelight.com/boom3d/mas-content/uninstall.php for uninstalling Boom 3D by the way. It's also from the developer.

Answer (score 0):

answer for non-kext versions (recent mac os versions):

I found this file

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.globaldelight.Boom2Daemon/Data/Library/Preferences/com.globaldelight.Boom2Daemon.plist
```

inside it there is an uninstaller link:

```
% defaults read /System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.globaldelight.Boom2Daemon/Data/Library/Preferences/com.globaldelight.Boom2Daemon.plist | grep https
kBoomDaemonSandBoxUrl = "https://www.globaldelight.com/boom2/mas-content/uninstaller.php?app_version=1.7.12";
```

opening the link downloads the uninstaller for the version that was installed

run the uninstaller and reboot. the audio device will be gone.