# How to uninstall Boom and find BoomDevice

Tags: macbook-pro

Please tell me if this instruction is for a Mac or PC. I can't find it on my MacBook Pro Mavericks.  check for BoomDevice.kext in System/Library/Extensions

I also cannot find where uninstall is located. Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete the Boom application output device from my system?](http://superuser.com/questions/868637/how-can-i-delete-the-boom-application-output-device-from-my-system)

Answer (score 0):

Open Boom application->Settings->Click "Uninstall" from left bottom corner(red font) very well hidden.