# How to delete "BoomAudio" from sound settings in mac os Ventura?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, uninstall, macos-ventura

Even after uninstalling the Boom2 app using its own uninstaller and following all the instructions from:
[How can I delete the Boom application output device from my system?](https://superuser.com/questions/868637/how-can-i-delete-the-boom-application-output-device-from-my-system)

I can still see "BoomAudio" in my audio settings (see attached images).

How do I remove this and any other leftover parts of boom completely ?

I'm on mac os Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68)

Attached images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZJcM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ol5.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here's what worked for me:

I downloaded the [BoomAudio Uninstaller](https://www.globaldelight.com/boom3d/mas-content/uninstall.php) for Boom 3D and ran it. Note: I also had already uninstalled the Boom app from my computer (i.e. exactly the same issue you are having). By running the Uninstaller (and without rebooting), the BoomAudio 'virtual device' disappeared!

Hope this works for you too.